# Вывод комментариев

Tags: php, mysql

Я сделал вывод комментариев на на сайте и прикрутил лайки и дизлайки теперь нужно узнать на каком комментарии нажата кнопка и ввести в базу

Answer (score 2):

Передавать ID комментария. Если без перезагрузки то ajax, если с перезагрузкой то по клику на ссылку